# Why does next.js call getStaticPaths on every load of a page?

Tags: next.js

I have a series of product detail pages I'm pre-rendering, and expected that within the revalidation period Next would not need to call `getStaticPaths` when refreshing the page I'm on. Similar to their example here I wanted to pretender a number of top products. I found that in development, it was calling `getStaticPaths` on every refresh or URL change even when it was to the page I'm already on. The problem this surfaces is that during development, when testing functionality requiring a URL param change, `getStaticPaths` would be called and the page would be unresponsive during this time. In the example below, I'd rather get 1000 products, but reduced to 10 so I could develop.

TL;DR why does Next.js call this function on every page load, and is this a development-only behavior?

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  console.log("Getting static paths");
  let listingHandles: { __typename: string; handle: string }[] = [];
  // fetch 10 product handles at a time, the api is sensitive
  async function* productOffsetGenerator() {
    let offset = 0;
    while (offset < 10) {
      yield (offset += 10);
    }
  }

  for await (const offset of productOffsetGenerator()) {
    const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
      query: GET_LISTINGS_HANDLE,
      variables: {
        offset,
      },
    });
    listingHandles = [...listingHandles, ...data.listedListings.listings];
  }

  const paths = listingHandles.map((edge: { handle: string }) => ({
    params: { handle: edge.handle },
  }));

  return {
    fallback: "blocking",
    paths,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> is this a development-only behavior

Confirmed this behavior does occur only in development.